# ¿WPF El subproceso que realiza la llamada no puede obtener acceso?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-forms, wpf, net

En mi proyecto WPF estoy intentando hacer que el icono de la aplicación en la barra de tareas parpadee utilizando el siguiente post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924556/force-window-to-blink-when-a-particular-event-occurs-in-c-sharp-wpf

Pero cuando llamo al metodo FlashApplicationWindow(); me manda el siguiente error

> El subproceso que realiza la llamada no puede obtener accesoa este
> objeto porque el propietario es otro subproceso

Intente meter el llamado de FlashApplicationWindow(); dentro **BackgroundWorker** pero sigue enviando el mismo error.

Alguien me puede ayudar a como debe de realizarse el llamado porfavor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo habitual es que una aplicación trabaje sobre un mismo hilo todo el tiempo, pero cuando usas multi-threading, ya sea a través de BackgroundWorker, Task, Thread u otros, se crean nuevos hilos y esos nuevos hilos no pueden modificar el hilo principal, que es el que maneja la interfaz de usuario, por eso aparece ese mensaje, porque tratas de hacer algo con un elemento de la interfaz desde un hilo distinto al de ella..

La solución clásica a este problema se puede resumir en meter tus llamadas dentro de esto:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //INSTRUCCIONES A LA UI
    }));
```

Y listo, con esto estás diciéndole al compilador que ejecute tus instrucciones en el hilo principal, no es necesario meter todo el contenido de un método, basta solo con la parte que tiene que ver con la interfaz.